# SSAS Cube Processing fails in deployment stage

Tags: ssas, bids

I am trying to process Cube and keep getting following error in deployment stage:

*Error  15  Internal error: An unexpected error occurred (file 'pfcrypt.cpp', line 2100, function 'PFCryptKey::ExportKeyToFile').*

The cube was processing successfully earlier and the only change I can think of is that the server password was changed. However I have effected the changes in Analysis service so that should not be the problem.

EDIT: Deleting the SSAS database and then deploying Cube resolved the issue. The underlying issue which caused the error is still unknown.

Answer (score 0):

That maybe happened because you upgraded an older version solution to a newer. Check this [Migrating OLAP SSAS 2005 Database to SQL 2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/karang/2010/08/10/migrating-olap-ssas-2005-database-to-sql-2008/) to understand the migration steps.